# How can I get a better understanding of garbage collection in html5?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

When working with html5, I was trying to write a game on the canvas, but once I would have the animations open for about 5-10 minutes garbage collection would become so frequent that I couldn't play the game because the whole canvas would begin to completely glitch out.

I am using ezpz.js @ ezpzjs.org. ezpz.js attempts to recreate the magic of codeskulptor, but codeskulptor can only run in a popup window.

This is not the same program, but in principal it is very similar with more objects moving around.

Seen in action here: http://www.ezpzjs.org/PicExplore.html

```
<script>
// var load;
var ww = "background.jpg";
var yy = "cards_jfitz.png";
ImageLoad(yy);
ImageLoad(ww);
var Pos = [1493, 675];
var XVel = 0;
var YVel = 0;


// name, width, height
canvas("myCanvas", 500, 500);



// Function From Timer
function MadAlerts()
    {

//                 name,  loc, x-Cen-Src, Y-Cen-Src,widnip,htnip, x placement, y place, wid of place, ht of place, roatation


    canvasComplexImage("myCanvas", ww, Pos[0], Pos[1], 500, 500, 250, 250, 500, 500, 0);
    canvasComplexImage("myCanvas", yy, 36, 48, 72, 96, 250, 250, 72, 96, 0);
    Pos[0] = Pos[0] + XVel;
    Pos[1] = Pos[1] + YVel;


}

window.onkeydown = KeydownControl;
window.onkeyup = KeyupControl;

// Keydown Handler
function KeydownControl(e)
    {
    if (KeyFinder(e.keyCode) == "Right")
        {
        XVel = 4;
        }
    if (KeyFinder(e.keyCode) == "Left")
        {
        XVel = -4;
        }
    if (KeyFinder(e.keyCode) == "Up")
        {
        YVel = -4;
        }
    if (KeyFinder(e.keyCode) == "Down")
        {
        YVel = 4;
        }
    }

// Keyup Handler

function KeyupControl(e)
    {
    if (KeyFinder(e.keyCode) == "Right")
        {
        if (XVel == -4)
            {
            XVel = -4;
            }
        else
            {
            XVel = 0;
            }
        }
    if (KeyFinder(e.keyCode) == "Left")
        {
        if (XVel == 4)
            {
            XVel = 4;
            }
        else
            {
            XVel = 0;
            }
        }
    if (KeyFinder(e.keyCode) == "Up")
        {
        if (YVel == 4)
            {
            YVel == 4;
            }
        else
            {
            YVel = 0;
            }
        }
    if (KeyFinder(e.keyCode) == "Down")
            {
        if (YVel == -4)
            {
            YVel = -4;
            }
        else
            {
            YVel = 0;
            }
        }
    }

// Timer Name, Timer Var, Incremental (similar to codeskulptor), function to call
TimerInterval("MyTimer", "TimerVar", 15, MadAlerts);
```

Comment: If you want to understand how GC works, then you'd need to read either SpiderMonkey or v8 source codes to know how they are implemented in open sources browsers, while keeping in mind other engines may very well  have different implementations. But seriously, that's way too broad to provide an answer for SO format, that could take books. Now, you normally don't need a deep understanding of how this works, if it kicks in, it's because you are producing too much trash. From the code you gave, the only new objects that could get created would be in `canvasComplexImage`. Show its content to us.

Comment: Thank you for this input. I think this is exactly what I was looking for.